# RVIZ Interactive Markers - color change runtime

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering if it was possible to change the color of an Interactive Markers during run time?
I tried to change the color of the mesh embedded in the Interactive Markers but nothing occurs when I update the Server:

```
server.get()->applyChanges();
```

The architecture of my Interactive Markers is :

```
visualization_msgs::Marker robot_mesh;
visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerControl robot_control; //contain robot_mesh
visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker robot_marker; //contain robot_control
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171706/rviz-interactive-markers---color-change-runtime/) by [thomasL](https://answers.ros.org/users/16906/thomasl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A solution that worked for me was to just clear all interactive markers and reinsert them all with the new colors. Surprisingly, this works even while a marker is being dragged in rviz

---

Originally posted by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) with karma: 111 on 2016-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1